# Building Resilient Spiders Against Inconsistent HTML markup

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get player and referee content from this site and store it in a db. At first, when I looked through it, all the players and the referees were in response.css("div.prelims p.indent::text"), and I could use regex to parse the ones with players from the ones with referees. No problem.

Then I took a harder look at the rest of the site, only to see that they DO NOT follow this structure consistently. Here is an example:

```
<div class="prelims">
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p1">
  <span class="num">1</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p2">
  <span class="num">2</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p3">
  <span class="num">3</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p4">
  <span class="num">4</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p5">
  <span class="num">5</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about referee.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p6">
```

Not only does this page have this 'num' and 'span' that the other page didn't, but my regex, which worked fine on the test page, breaks on the first p class=indent here.

What are some general principles of spider design that can make my spider more resilient against all this variability, and still be able to get the results into the right tables in my db? I am using DjangoItem, and was looking forward to a smooth pipeline into my db, but now I may have to wrangle this data to even get it into the right shape to insert. Your wisdom, insight, and experience greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can ignore the `div` tags if all the `p` tags that you want to capture have the indent class:

```
import re

text = r'''
<div class="prelims">
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p1">
  <span class="num">1</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p2">
  <span class="num">2</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p3">
  <span class="num">3</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p4">
  <span class="num">4</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about players.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p5">
  <span class="num">5</span>
  <p class="indent">Text about referee.</p>
</div>
<div class="num" id="p6">
'''

pattern = re.compile(r"<p.*class=[\"\']indent[\"\'].*>(.+)<\/p>", re.MULTILINE)

for m in re.findall(pattern, text):
    print(m)
```

Output:

```
Text about players.
Text about players.
Text about players.
Text about players.
Text about players.
Text about referee.
```